Georeferencing HiRISE images (Martian North) in QGIS 3.36 for geometric calculations
I want to run various geometric measurements on Martian structures in QGIS. Therefore I downloaded a JP2 Black and white map-projected HiRISE image (https://www.uahirise.org/PSP_007372_2475). As I am new to planetary QGIS, I don't know how to find the correct projection for the image so I can measure the features.
What I did so far (exactly what is explained here:

Opened an empty QGIS project file
Created a new projection  by going to "preferences" -> "personalize projection".
Added the projection IAU2000:49910: Mars Equidistant Cylindrical in the WKT Format.
Loaded the HiRISE JP2-image ("add raster layer")
Changed the project projection to IAU2000:49910

Afterwards, when using the "measure line" tool in QGIS the measurements seem to be wrong:
QGIS measurement:
diameter of the crater = ca. 56 km

Compared to Google Mars
diameter of the crater = ca. 14 km

Do I need a different kind of projection, as the location is quite far north on Mars and how do I know when it is correct?

One question per Question, please. A numbered list of questions will generate close votes.

Sorry, just edited it.

The phrase "changed the projection" sends up alarm bells.  Did you replace the existing projection (effectively providing metadata that lies to the software about where the data is located), or did you reproject the data? Please [Edit] the Question to provide the exact procedure.

I hope my workflow is a bit clearer now? I have changed the pojection of the project from Earth projection to Mars.

Plate carrée isn't going to cut it for mensuration far from the standard parallel (equator). You need a conic or transverse Mercator (or, if it's really far north, a polar stereographic).

I have tried so many different projections (e. g.: Mars_2000_North_Pole_Stereographic_sphere - link: https://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/103883/#), but I always get the wrong scale (always 56 km). Can you recommend a polar stereographic WKT?
